# PATCH Request in Java using MSAL (msal-client-credential-secret)

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I'm using client credential secret to run API on Microsoft Endpoint (Intune).
Example used from [link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-daemon/tree/master/msal-client-credential-secret).

- Getting access token. (Working)
- Get android Managed App Protections. (Working using GET HTTP Method)
- Patch Request. (**Not Working**)

The examples do not mention any PATCH or POST request, hence need some help for it.

I tried the below code snippet but it fails.

```
private void setAndroidModels(final String accessToken, final String policyId, final String modelList)
        throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(
            "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/androidManagedAppProtections/" + policyId);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.setRequestMethod("PATCH");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    try (OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream()) {
        byte[] input = modelList.getBytes();
        os.write(input, 0, input.length);
    }

    int httpResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("POST Response Code :  " + httpResponseCode);
    System.out.println("POST Response Message : " + conn.getResponseMessage());
}
```

Result : **Exception in thread "main" java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid HTTP method: PATCH**

Also tried

```
private void setAndroidModels(final String accessToken, final String policyId, final String modelList)
        throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(
            "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/androidManagedAppProtections/" + policyId);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.setRequestProperty("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "PATCH");
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    try (OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream()) {
        byte[] input = modelList.getBytes();
        os.write(input, 0, input.length);
    }

    int httpResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("POST Response Code :  " + httpResponseCode);
    System.out.println("POST Response Message : " + conn.getResponseMessage());
}
```

Result :
**POST Response Code :  400
POST Response Message: Bad Request**

How can I get the client credential secret logic working for POST and PATCH HTTP Methods?

Comment: I would try the following, (1) Try the above Graph API calls in MS Graph Explorer or POSTMAN and see if it works (2) Try adding MSAL logging for Java to get more logging info - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-logging?tabs=java

Comment: the Graph API calls are already working in both Graph Explorer and Postman. However im unable to get the PATCH requests in MSAL

Comment: Tried using MSAL Logging using the logback but nothing captured in it.

Answer (score 0):

We can directly call patch request in MS Graph.

> When creating PATCH requests to the API, you need to create a new
> PATCH object that contains only the information you want to update.
> This should be distinct from any objects you receive from the service
> from a GET or a POST.

Please refer [Document](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/wiki/Patching-objects) for more details.

**For example,** Patch rquest to user

```
User realMe = graphClient.me().buildRequest().get();


User patchMe = new User();
patchMe.givenName = "Beth";


realMe = graphClient
    .users(realMe.userPrincipalName)
    .buildRequest()
    .patch(patchMe);
```